# Copy few values from an ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I copy values from an `ArrayList` to another. if I have an `ArrayList` containing 10 values and I want to copy the 2nd 4th values and so on.

Here's my code:

```
ArrayList tab = new ArrayList();    
ArrayList tab2 = new ArrayList();    
{    
    int i=1;    
    int j=0;    
    while (i < tab.size()){    
        tab.get(i);    
        i=i+2;    
        tab2.add(i);    
        j=j+1;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: If I correctly understand what you want, you'll need to assign a variable to the result of the `get` call - something like `int toCopy = tab.get(i);`  and then when you want to use it, you'll actually write `tab2.add(toCopy);`.  Give that a try.

Comment: What exactly is the `4rd` value? Do you just mean every other index?

Comment: yes 4rd is index

eg: 4 5 9 8 7

I just want to copy 4 9 7 to another arraylist

Comment: Do you have any pattern? Every even values will be copied right?

Comment: Come on, it's obvious from the excerpt that he/she intends to copy every second value.

Comment: @DavidWallace primarily I also thought so. but when OP said `yes 4rd is index eg: 4 5 9 8 7 I just want to copy 4 9 7 to another arraylist` I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to do something as:

```
ArrayList tab = new ArrayList();    
ArrayList tab2 = new ArrayList();    
int count = 0;

for(Object t : tab) {
    if(count%2==0 && count >= 2) {
        tab2.add(t.clone());
    }

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> arr1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(3);
    arr.add(4);
    arr.add(5);
    arr.add(6);
    arr.add(7);
    arr.add(8);
    arr.add(9);
    arr.add(10);
    System.out.println(arr);
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        if(i%2!=0){
            arr1.add(arr.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arr1);
    }
Input:`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Output:`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`
```